# Is it possible to ignore HTML5 validation a specific button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

Similar to the following question (*note the following question is related to symfony 2.3 - I don't know what that is, I'm just using HTML*) :

[How to disable html5-validation for specific buttons in symfony 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068778/how-to-disable-html5-validation-for-specific-buttons-in-symfony-2-3)

Is it possible to bypass HTML5 validation (`required`) for a specific button in HTML?

```
<form name="loginform" autocomplete="off" id="loginform" action="" method="post">
            <nav class="clearfix">
                <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><input class="username" type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Username"></li>
                    <li><input class="password" type="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password"></li>
                    <li><button name="register" class="register">Register</button>
                    <button name="login" class="login">Log in</button></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
            </nav>
    </form>
```

I don't need validation if **register** button is clicked.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    header("Location: register.php");
}
```

Edit: A way of doing this without changing the structure of the form or changing the button :).

Comment: how bout removing the other buttons on clicking the register button? OR have the register button in a different formset?

Comment: I didn't get the first part of your comment... I have already made tons of styling, don't want to change my structure. It would be good to know if there is a way... I can just change the button to a anchor link...

Comment: There are many ways of doing this depending on how you want to proceed: take the button out of the `form`, turn the button into an anchor, pre-process the buttons with JS...

Comment: I am aware that I can just change to button to an anchor link like I stated on my previous comment but I want to know if there is a way without changing the structure of the form or the button.

Comment: I don't generally work with symfony - but is there any reason you can't just remove the `name` attribute on the button and be fine?

Comment: I'm not working with symfony either, you must of misread the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click event listener to the register button. When it is clicked, do whatever you want to do (redirect with `window.location = "....."`), and return false to prevent default submission:

```
$("#register").on("click", function() {
    alert("I am executed before the HTML5 check!");
    return false;
});
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/89z4Lu91/

Comment: Use the `formnovalidate` attribute. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/89z4Lu91/1/

Comment: BTW, the `formnovalidate` solution came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725078/bypass-html-required-attribute-when-submitting (you can find a good explanation and sources there)

Comment: Hah! You are a star! I did see that somewhere before I asked the question but it was only for the whole form... Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

To the register button only use `<a href="bla">register</a>` or put the botons out and to the inputs submit add form attr

Comment: Read my comment above please.

Comment: have you tried the form attribute in the register button? (option without js and adding a empty form :S)

Comment: Alvaro Montoro comment another options too